Why are my Textures, Bezier Circles and Boolean Cuts Not Exporting?
When I render my image in Blender using F12, it looks like this:

When I export it to .glb or .fbx and import it into Godot, it looks like this:

I have tried selecting everything in the scene but the light and camera; and, deleting the light and camera and exporting everything.
Do I need to do additional processing? I notice that the letters at the top are exported with the correct texture, but nothing else is textured. The bezier circles I'm using for text curvature aren't showing up either. Also, the cylinders I'm using for the cuts were showing up when I selected everything. Now they're not when I delete the light and camera for export. But either way, the boolean cuts I'm doing with them are not happening.

See: .fbx export why there are no materials or textures. Also you can't export Blender's modifiers. You have to apply them first which is an option in the exporter.

This helped, thank you. I was able to apply the modifiers, and recreate the texture in Godot. The gold color working on one piece was because I had two textures applied, and it actually exported to Godot because it was BSDF.

Good! I should have added that you also have to delete the boolean cutters after applying the modifiers or they would be exported with your model but you obviously realised that (and presumably the exporter handles that if you set it to apply them on export).

Yeah, I did. If you wanted to make your comment an answer, I could accept it. :)
